# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem and i dont know how to fix it . Iam getting this errors but i am not sure if this error apear cause i am trying to call 2  functions with extends

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:786)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:685)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:642)



        at mylogin.Orders.executeSQLQuery(Orders.java:147)
        at mylogin.Orders.Make_OrderActionPerformed(Orders.java:439)
        at mylogin.Orders.access$100(Orders.java:23)
```

Here is my code that appear  to having  the problem  (at mylogin.Orders.executeSQLQuery(Orders.java:147))

```
  //execute the sql query REFRESH JTABLE 
          public void  executeSQLQuery (String query,String message) {
        Connection con =getConnection();
        Statement stt;
        Statement sttt;
        try{
            stt =con.createStatement();
            sttt =con.createStatement();
           // **1 error 147**
            if(((stt.executeUpdate(query))==1) || ((sttt.executeUpdate(query)) )==1)

            {
                //refresh jtable data
                DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Orders.getModel();

                model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_Prordes.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
                show_Products_in_Jtable();
                show_Orders_in_Jtable();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
            }

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Here is my code that appear  to having  the problem (at mylogin.Orders.Make_OrderActionPerformed)

```
  private void Make_OrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     String query="INSERT INTO Orders(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Order_Quantity,Order_Date,Order_Id)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Order_Quantity.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Date.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Id.getText()+" ') ";
     executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
    }
```

and finnaly this point (at mylogin.Orders.access$100)

```
public class Orders extends  javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Orders
     */
    public Orders() {
        initComponents();
       show_Products_in_Jtable();
       show_Orders_in_Jtable();  
    }
```

i am stuck at this points for days any help ??? ty !!!

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear. BTW you should learn about prepared statements

Comment: "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause" which part of that statement is it that you don't understand?

Comment: You miss a singlequote: `,'"+Order_Quantity.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Date`

Comment: that is why java binding might save some brain cells moving forward

Comment: Cobbling together SQL statements like that is *asking* for trouble and pain, and not only with debugging. [Learn to use prepared statements.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: ty very much Jens !!! that was pfff really ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ommiting a this symbol ' after `,'"+Order_Date.getText()+"'`

```
INSERT INTO Orders(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Order_Quantity,Order_Date,Order_Id)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Order_Quantity.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Date.getText()+"' ,'"+Order_Id.getText()+" ') "
```

this is better

```
String query = " insert into Orders(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Order_Quantity,Order_Date,Order_Id)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


  PreparedStatement Stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  preparedStmt.setString (1, Pro_Id.getText());
  preparedStmt.setString (2, Order_Quantity());
  preparedStmt.setDate   (3, Order_Quantity.getText());
  preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, Order_Date.getText());
  preparedStmt.setInt    (5, Order_Id.getText());


 Stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mistake:

```
INSERT INTO Orders(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Order_Quantity,Order_Date,Order_Id)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Order_Quantity.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Date.getText()+" ,'"+Order_Id.getText()+" ') "
```

Comment: What is the mistake? The query itself?